# Clickonce application is already installed in another location. Please uninstall application

Tags: c#, clickonce

I'm facing some issues in the auto-updating for clickonce application. It keeps prompting this exception in the details log:
System.Deployment.Application.Deployment.Exception(GroupMultipleMatch). 
I have tried researching around but nothing comes up. 
Need to resolve this error soon, anyone have an idea on this exception?

```
Here's the error detail log:
Component Store transaction failure summary
No transaction error was detected.

Warnings
The manifest for this application does no have a signature. signature validation will be ignored.
The manifest for this application does no have a signature. signature validation will be ignored.

Operation Progress Status:
[9/14/2018 5:21:05 PM] : Activation of C:\Program Files\user\Browsersetup\application.appref-ms
[9/14/2018 5:21:05 PM] : Performing necessary update check as specified by the deployment
[9/14/2018 5:21:05 PM] : Consuming new update
[9/14/2018 5:21:05 PM] : Installation of the application has started
[9/14/2018 5:21:05 PM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed
[9/14/2018 5:21:06 PM] : Found compatible run time version 4.0.30319
[9/14/2018 5:21:10 PM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete
[9/14/2018 5:21:10 PM] : Downloading of subscription dependencies is complete
[9/14/2018 5:21:10 PM] : Commit of the downloaded application has started.

Error details
Following errors were detected during this operation. 
[[9/14/2018 5:21:11 PM] : System.Deployment.Application.Deployment.Exception(GroupMultipleMatch)
- Application is already installed from another location. Please uninstall application.
- Source: System Deployment
- Stack trace:
 at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CommitApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, CommitApplicationParams commitParams)
 at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
 at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ConsumeUpdatedDeployment(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription 
actDesc)  
 at  System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentUpdate(SubscriptionState&subState, String&errorPageUrl)
 at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ProcessOrFollowShortcut(String shortcutFile, String&errorPageUrl, TempFile&deployFile)
 at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId,String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension,BrowserSettings browserSettings, String errorPageUrl) 
 at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
```

Comment: Have you changed the publish location path?

Comment: The publish location path have remained the same, no changes was done

Comment: Open the file `C:\Program Files\user\Browsersetup\application.appref-ms
` in notepad, what is its content? does it start with your publish location?

Comment: let me check on it and get back to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to 'Programs and Features' in the 'Control Panel'
2. Find your program in the list of programs
3. RightClick it and Uninstall.
4. Then run the Publish again.

Comment: Thanks, but i need to do as auto update on this application. Upon restarting of the computer. It is suppose to read the latest version of the application from the server, download and install it.

Comment: ClickOnce will auto update. The problem is that this same application has been installed from a different location. This must be uninstalled only once by the user.

Or you can return the location back to the original one.
See the 3rd line in the Error Details section in the Error Detail log

Comment: Hi Yakov, after I tried that method, another error pop up - Access is denied , during the auto-update. Seems like the cache folder is not properly cleared after the installation.A full permission right was given to the user account. Is there any way to workaround this issue other than manually clearing the cache folder?

Comment: @Amy you might need to give 'Local Administrator' rights to the user that is running the auto-update.